# Grub Rescue - LVM ID not found

Tags: debian, grub, raid

I freshly installed system on my HW RAID 0 drives, over which is installed SW Raid 1 with LVM. After Installation of Debian 10, I've got this problem which I don't know how to resolve.
[image]

I tried so far, completly wipe drives, create own LVM in live image, which worked, tryed to force new UUID. Nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the end, I buildet RAID 1 with HW raid, and created LVM.

Seems like the HW RAID did not liked solution with two raid 0, and over them one raid 1 with LVM.

Answer (score 0):

If your system uses UEFI, then access the EFI System Partition (ESP) using a live boot media or whatever. It is normally a small FAT32 partition. Once you have it mounted somewhere, you'll find a tiny GRUB configuration file at `<mountpoint>/EFI/debian/grub.cfg`. It is actually just a reference to the location of the actual GRUB configuration file. On my system, where `/boot` is a normal GPT partition (not within LVM), the file looks like this:

```
search.fs_uuid 1406433d-b809-4e38-adea-94f1b95ae313 root 
set prefix=($root)'/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg
```

On your system, the first line is probably different and mentions the (now obsolete) LVM ID. Make sure that it correctly references the filesystem that contains your `/boot/grub` directory; even though it mentions `root`, **it does not necessarily mean the root filesystem of the Linux OS**, but just the root of the GRUB's directory structure, which may be a part of the root filesystem or a separate `/boot` filesystem.